# Unable to retrieve metadata for my model, NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: Error Message]

I have been trying to fix my error for 2 hours but every attempt comes to no avail. What I've been trying to do is follow [this MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model) step 4-6.

1.) What I did is I created a model with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Bakunawa.Models
{
    public class BakunawaModels
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public TextBox Memo { get; set; }
    }

    public class BakunawaDBContext : DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<BakunawaModels> Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2.) Then added my connection string in the Web.Config file:

```
    <add name="BakunawaDBContext"connectionString="Data Source (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Notes.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

3.) Finally, I tried to add my controller (scaffolding) like this:

[image: 3rd step]

However, as shown above, the program states an error message.
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'BakunawaModels.BakunawaModels'.
Object reference not set to an instance
of an object.

Troubleshooting steps I did was: 
1. Build, Rebuild, and Clean the program. 
2. Restart the computer. 
3. I checked google for relevant answers, to no avail. [My google search](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=Unable%20to%20retrieve%20metadata%20for%20''.%20Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object&es_th=1) 
4. I checked stack overflow for this as well, similar questions popped up and I tried stuff like: 
a. changing the connection string to "System.Data.SqlClient" 
b. my search for stack overflow: [My stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable%20to%20retrieve%20metadata%20for%20%27%27.%20Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object) 
5. I created another program and followed the tutorial word-for-word, and it works so I know something is wrong with my code. Kindly enlighten me.

Comment: What is typeof `TextBox`? Why do you have a reference to WebForms controls in MVC? Suggest you change `TextBox Memo` to `string Memo`

Comment: I tried that earlier, however the error message pops-up 
"Unable to retrieve Metadata for 'Bakunawa.Models.BakunawaModels'. Keyword not supported: 'attach dbfilename'."
The reason I put TextBox there is because I wanted to have a TextArea  instead of a string. Thank you though.

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea that you use WebForms controls in a MVC app. Step 1: Find and delete all `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` through out your project and then remove the assembly from your project. Next, change your property to `public string Memo { get; set; }` (you create a `<textarea>` element using `@Html.TextAreaFor()` in your view). How could your database possibly know what a web forms control is and how to store it!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a WebControl in your model.  You should change `Memo` from a `TextBox` to a `string`